# Request from Ajax to Spring MVC. 404 error

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am new in Spring MVC and I have problem with request. 
I got 404 error in my browser console. What should I change in my code? I think that xml files are wrong. i would be grateful for your reply

```
function login() {
var data = {};
var url = "/loginUser";
data["name"] = $("#loginName").val();
data["password"] = $("#loginPassword").val();
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data: 'name=' + data['name'] + '&password=' + data["password"],
    success: function () {
        console.log("Success")
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log("ERR")
        //...
    }
});
}
```

Spring MVC:

```
@Controller
public class AjaxLoginController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/loginUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String loginUser(@RequestParam(value="name") String name, @RequestParam(value="password") String password) {
    System.out.println(name);
    return "" ;
  }
}
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
   <!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
    <beans
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
         xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"

        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc             http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd     
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="login.html">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="login" />    

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources location="resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
<mvc:resources location="WEB-INF/" mapping="/WEB-INF/**" />
```

web.xml

```
  <web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
        <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener- class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
         <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
       <servlet- class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: it doesn't work :/

Comment: Are you deploying your app to tomcat or jetty or something? If so, you should prepend your context path to every url..Also add more details about your project structure and configurations

Comment: I'm using Glassfish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`url` in AJAX should be: `"loginUser.html"` accordingly to `<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>` in `web.xml`